Debugging in Rider or WebStorm won't hit any breakpoints for React Native applications
When running a React Native application for an iOS device, WebStorm or Rider won't hit any breakpoints. By using the default React Native run/debug configuration and the parameter --device "iPhone".
I'm not using expo or Hermes, it is a basic React Native application.
It seems as if it can't attach to the debugger.
